# absolute_results for friends:members loop

Tags: solspace, solspace-friends

Friends member loop doesn't recognize friends_absolute_results, however it does recognize friends_total_results. I am using pagination, so I want it to say "total_results" out of "absolute_results". How do I go about this?

Comment: What version of Friends and EE are you using? Also, can you post the code that you have up to now? Thanks. :)

Comment: Friends 1.6.2 and EE (2.6.1)

Comment: {exp:friends:members limit="4" paginate="bottom"}
{if friends_count == "1"}<h6>Displaying {friends_total_results} of {absolute_results}</h6>{/if}

{exp:friends:members}